# enter (into) society

Tags: collocations

Let's examine this context:

> Part-time jobs can help students develop real-world skills that will come in handy when they graduate and **enter into society**.

I thought when students are in school, they are already in society. Therefore, I would write:

> Part-time jobs can help students develop real-world skills that will come in handy when they graduate and **enter into workplace**.

Is "enter into society" an idiomatic expression in English? Is there a difference between "enter into society" and "enter society"?

Comment: Arguably, a child 'enters society' when he or she is born.

Comment: I agree with James K that this usage is idiomatic (though to my twentieth-century American eyes, ears, and brain, "enter society" is more natural than "enter into society.") However, I share your view that "when students are in school, they are already in society." I'd therefore be more inclined to use a phrase like "when they graduate and **become full-fledged members of** society." And there are many contexts in which "graduate and enter the workforce" would also be a perfectly fine alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is idiomatic usage.  It can be taken to mean "the wider society, beyond the protective layer of school and parents"

Similarly, you will sometimes see "real-world examples of mathematics" as distinct from "school or textbook examples".  And yet the textbook is part of the real world.  However, we understand these words to mean the world or the society *beyond school".

"Workplace" doesn't work well as an alternative.  Some students won't enter the workplace.  Some might become dependent on a spouse. Or some might have children and their "workplace" is the home.  Yet these people have still entered society beyond school.